# How to add jquery datepicker to dynamically created input which lives in an ajax called page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

Forgive me if this has been answered, but I have searched this site using creative versions of different search terms and came up blank.

I have a `php` webpage (index.php), that uses `ajax` to load another `php` page (dataQuery.php) which has an `html` form on it. I have created a small script (`addInput()`) that allows the user to dynamically add as many input fields to this form as they like. One of these fields is a date field that I would like to have a datepicker attached to. In the past I have included any `javascript` to the `ajax` callback, however in this case I could not get it to work.

Here is my `function Query()`:

```
function Query()    
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    { 
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    // Tried this suggestion found on stackoverflow:
    $('body').on('focus',".newlabour_date", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();});

    // And this one:
    $( "#newlabour_date" ).datepicker();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/process/dataQuery.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is my `function addInput()`

```
function addInput(table,counter,rowcount)
{
var counter = document.getElementById(counter);
var number = counter.value;
counter.value = ++counter.value;

var rowcount = (rowcount*1+1); // muliply the rowcount by 1 to ensure it doesn't get treated as a concatenation.

var table = document.getElementById(table);
var row = table.insertRow(rowcount);
row.align = "center";

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.className = "bBottom";
cell1.width = "20%";
cell1.height = "21";

cell1.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" style=\"position:relative; top:2px;\"
class=\"noborder\" name=\"newlabour_date["+number+"]\" id=\"newlabour_date["+number+"]\" size=\"15\" maxlength=\"\" placeholder=\"\" value=\"\">";
}
```

I don't know if this is possible, but I have a feeling it is. Appreciate any help.

Comment: its unclear what you mean. i think you want the ajax callback function to trigger addInput, and then you want to initialize the datepicker once you have it in the DOM on the page. is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors with your code, you have missed the **newlabour_date** for the generated input field
and `table.insertRow(rowcount);` giving out of rage error.

A working example without Ajax:
http://jsfiddle.net/qxarbpcc/

Here is the updated version of your addInput function:

```
function addInput(table,counter,rowcount)
{
    var counter = document.getElementById(counter);
    var number = counter.value;
    counter.value = ++counter.value;

    var rowcount = parseInt(rowcount)+1; // muliply the rowcount by 1 to ensure it doesn't get treated as a concatenation.

    var table = document.getElementById(table);
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    row.align = "center";

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.className = "bBottom";
    cell1.width = "20%";
    cell1.height = "21";

    cell1.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" style=\"position:relative; top:2px;\" class=\"noborder newlabour_date\" name=\"newlabour_date["+number+"]\" id=\"newlabour_date["+number+"]\" size=\"15\" maxlength=\"\" placeholder=\"\" value=\"\">";
}
```

Then change your Ajax callback to this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{ 
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    $('body').on('focus',".newlabour_date", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();});
}
```

Don't forget to add jquery and jqueryui in head section.

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: every script in the loaded page via your code will be treated as plain text ... not javascript, so you should execute your scripts manually

Comment: there are some errors in your code, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65457/discussion-between-ammar-and-andrew-fox).